# Install Symfony 2.8 in Windows 8 PC, Xampp

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, phar

Well i know it is not depends on Operating System when it is about to install any PHP framework. But what my issue is i am trying to install it by symfony.phar, the symfony installer provided by symfony itself. I have downloaded symfony in my XAMPP at

> C:\xaamp\htdocs\symfony\symfony.phar

Now i am following onscreen instruction given by symfony.phar and i execute following command at C:\xampp\htdocs\symfony:

> symfony.phar new blog

Commad works but it pop up Window screen to choose app for .phar file which you can check in attached screenshot. Can anyone help me with that?

[image]

Comment: Try with git-bash https://git-scm.com

php *.phar new blog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to execute it with PHP :

```
php symfony.phar new blog
```

If the PHP is not in your environment PATH, use the full path of the binary :

```
c:/path/to/php.exe symfony.phar new blog
```

Comment: I had to do small change in your command like this C:\xampp\php\php.exe  symfony.phar new blog and it works. thanks